# Firestore collection group query solution?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm saw that Firebase released [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which is awesome. So in the example in the docs:

> For example, this collection group query retrieves all museum landmarks across all cities

But how to get all cities that have museum landmarks? So I want to return city objects and not landmarks. How to solve this?

---

All I want to do is to get all the cities that have in their`landmarks` subcollection, landmarks that are museum? Is this possbile with collection group query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Queries return documents from the collections that you query. Since you're querying the `landmarks` collections, the results returned will be landmark documents.

If you want the parent city documents, you will have to load those individually and separately.

Alternatively: consider if you can't add an array to your city documents that allows you to perform your query on that collection with `array-contains`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is there any way I can query all cities that have museum landmarks?

Comment: I cannot use an array because the elements within the array are objects and not strings. So I cannot query using `array-contains`. I'm a little confused, what do you mean with "you will have to load those individually and separately"? All I want to do is to get all the cities that have in their` landmarks` subcollection, landmarks that are museum? Is this possbile with collection group query? Thanks

Comment: You can't query the `landmarks` subcollection and get results from a differently named collection.

Comment: @HansSpigel I ran into same kind of issue. Can you please help me understand how did you get cities that have museum landmarks?